# How to select the one before last entity in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I want to select the one before last row from my MySQL table.
Note- This data will be changed because there is also an adding data PHP file.

Here is my database:
[image: Here is my database]

Comment: What do you mean?  The row with the next to highest custId?

Comment: yes. I'm looking for something like DESC LIMIT 1 to use to get this row

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from TABLENAME where custid = 
(SELECT Max(custid) from TABLENAME WHERE id <
( SELECT Max(custid) from TABLENAME));
```

Replace the **TABLENAME** with the name of your table.

Comment: Very much not the most efficient way to do it

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * 
  From (Select *
          From TableName
          Order By custId Desc
          Limit 2)
  Order By custId Asc
  Limit 1
```

Try this. First I Select the last 2 rows ordered DESC. Than I order them ASC and select the first one.
Example: if we have [1,2,3,4,5,6], we need to select 5
So in the first query (with limit 2) I will get [6,5], Then I order this ASC to get [5,6] and select the first one.

PS: Replace TableName with your table name and hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from yoursecrettablename order by custId desc limit 1,1;
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html#idm139931865483920 for a description of the two-argument form of LIMIT.